# Troubleshooting Apple Push Notification Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

My push notifications were working roughly a month ago. I am working in production push notifications. I haven't worked on my project for a while because of other engagements, and when I came back, I was no longer able to send a push notification.

After creating a log that is linked up to my production sns, I've noticed this:

> "delivery": {
>           "deliveryId": "d3675e8a-45b0-58db-9b79-11e284987bbb",
>           "destination": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:445291524102:endpoint/APNS/BusyTime/587673f1-cf48-3b3e-9e74-04d39f8affc3",
>           "providerResponse": "NotificationErrorResponse(command=8, status=InvalidToken, id=1, cause=null)",
>           "dwellTimeMs": 319,
>           "attempts": 1,
>           "token": "55d7b18b064eecad93fb666818651d4f33b612487ee810b092f081cef41d4e43",
>           "statusCode": 8
>       },

After investigating the matter I started to try to check my credentials to see if I could get into the server.

I tried using the apple docs which led me to this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert BusyTimeProductionKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile ProductionAPS.pem
```

And I used Raywenderlich.com tutorial to set it up a while back and used this command to check it out again:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert ProductionAPS.pem -key BusyTimeProductionKey.pem
```

Both of which spit out a large amount of output and gave me this line to indicate that the connection was okay:
SSL handshake has read 3160 bytes and written 2319 bytes

However, I also noticed this line above everything that looked like it worked:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
```

Does the error line have anything to do with this error? If not, how should I approach fixing this problem of mine? Please keep in mind that I've set a debugging point in xcode, manually grabbed the device token for a device I'm testing, and inserted it into the sns console to isolate that it was not with a bad token. Thank you for your time and consideration. I also have a theory that I might not be using the correct provisioning profile. Would I need to check if I'm using the production provisioning profile? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that sns wasn't the problem, as I've stated in my question as well it was the APNS. I was downloading my application from xcode which I guess doesn't provide me with the correct device token for production. I still have yet to try it but when I reverted back to my most recent build that is on the app store, it started working. When I went to my actually most recent version on xcode, it stopped working. I guess the generation of the device token is different when on the app store and when not on the app store.

Comment: Yes, that is true. 

The APNs environment is split into "sandbox" and "production". When you run from Xcode or use a development signing certificate, the app will be in the "sandbox" environment. When installed from TestFlight, the App Store, or a package signed by a distribution certificate, it'll be in the "production" environment. 

Tokens created at run-time are specific to one environment, so you won't be able to send a "sandbox" token a notification using the "production" endpoint, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run the app directly from XCODE, you need to use the APNS_SANDBOX endpoint, not the APNS endpoint as in your above example. Once you "deploy" your app (via TestFlight or AppStore), then the non sandbox (APNS) endpoint will work.